# using ruby popen wrapped in a shell script

Tags: ruby, shell, command, stdout, popen

I finished my short file for a homework assignment which uses IO.popen("command").readlines to grab the STDOUT of that command. However, I need to write a shell script to wrap my ruby file in. No problem, but somehow putting it in the shell script makes readlines hang.

```
ruby script.rb foo example > example.out
```

this works

```
script.sh foo example >example.out
```

this hangs on readlines. `ruby script.rb` is all that script.sh contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to pass your arguments to the ruby command. You may also be failing to specify an interpreter

script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
ruby script.rb "$@"
```

Alternatively you could just add `#!/usr/bin/ruby` to the top of script.rb and make it executable (`chmod +x script.rb`). It's not a shell script. But it's generally the preferred way of executing a script in an interpretive language.

Once that's done you can run it with

`./script.rb`

Comment: should be /usr/bin/ruby (without "e" in user)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Sometimes the fingers are quicker than the brain.

Comment: alternatively, /usr/bin/env ruby